# TypeOrm - pass column result to a subquery

Tags: node.js, orm, subquery, typeorm, query-builder

I want to create a query builder in TypeOrm and search for accounts by some criteria, but I am using a subquery in the where clause, and there I have an equality check (id1 = id2), but one of them (ids) is coming from the initial "parent" query. Is there a way to "link" those queries? I'll explain what I mean:

```js
const subquery = this.reportEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder('rep')
   .subQuery()
   .select()
   .from(ReportEntity, 'rep')
   .where('profile_user_id = :user_id')
   .setParameter('user_id', **PARAM_HERE**)
   .getQueryAndParameters();

const accs = await this.accountEntityRepository.createQueryBuilder('acc')
   .select('*')
   .where(`NOT EXISTS ${subquery}`)
// .setParameters(here? but what?)
   .limit(count)
    .getRawMany<AccountEntity>();
```

Is this even possible to do it this way? Or by only coding the whole where clause as a string?

`NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM report WHERE profile_user_id = acc.user_id)`

Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks